# how to parse an array string into array

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a string into an array. The only catch is my string could have special character like `#` in it. Here is a sample input `"[1,2,3,#,5]"`. I tried using `JSON.parse` which works if there are no special characters, for eg, `"[1,2,3,4]"` but with special character like `#`, I want to keep the character as it is in the array. So `"[1,2,3,#,5]"` should be parsed as `[1,2,3,#,5]` but throws exception instead. `JSON.parse` provided a reviver callback function for special handling but seems to be an overkill for the purpose and I am guessing it would be a bit complicated. Any help is highly appreciated

Edit: Reviver callback would not help as it is for transforming parsed object, not for helping parse the object. So, that is also ruled out as possible solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const str = "[1,2,3,#,5]";

const arr = str.replace(/(^\[|\]$)/g, '')    // Remove the [] brackets
               .split(',')                   // Split on commas
               .map(x => isNaN(x) ? x : +x); // Convert numbers
               
console.log(arr); // [1, 2, 3, "#", 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is trying to convert it into number array, so any other character will throw an error including alphabets and special characters.

Try using this instead -

```js
var output = "[1,2,3,#,5]".replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'').split(",");
console.log(output);  //["1", "2", "3", "#", "5"]
```